# Infinite go back loop

Tags: laravel, routes, infinite-loop

I m building an app with a procedure to deposit folder so the user must browse different pages like this:

firstPage->secondPage->thirdPage...

So I used this:

```
 <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}"><input type="button" value="Go Back" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
```

But when I'm in the third page and go back it does:

thirdPage->secondPage->thirdPage...

With an infinite loop

How can I fix this?

Thank

Comment: it's it true? When you go back to the `second_page` from the `third_page`, the `third_page` becomes the previous one?

Comment: the previousUrl value became the third page.

Comment: You should maintain a stack and push or pop based on this.

Comment: I can do this by add a stack on session but if the user come back manually to Home I always add bad value in my session...

Comment: If the user goes to the home manually, clear the stack. otherwise, push/pop values. It's actually more of how you want it to be done. You have to put those logics in there.

Comment: I want that each go back button return to the last page but if I use a stack and the user change the url manually, the ga back don't send to the previous page (eq: thirdPage->secondPage(set by URL)->firstPage(go back button))
I want a go back always lead to the same page but i want to know if there is a solution without adding all routes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using {{ URL::previous() }} won't solve your problem, because imagine you're at second page then goes to third, then come back to second: At this moment, the previous page is the third one, that's why this is happening. So if you want to fix this, you'll have to know to where each page should go and place that logic there. So if page2 must go back to page1, you'll have to do something like this:

```
@if( Request::is('secondPage') ) 
    <script type="text/javascript">
             window.location = "{ url('/firstPage') }";
    </script>
@else
.....

@endif
```